Upgrading WildFly without upgrading JBoss EAP
Will there be any issues if wildfly-security is upgraded from 18.0.1.Final to 32.0.1.Final without upgrading the current version of JBoss EAP 7.4.1?

Moving code from a Jakarta EE server built on Java 11 to a Java EE server built on Java 7, not to mention without the dependency changes, what could go wrong ? Well a lot of things

What do you mean by "without upgrading JBoss EAP"?

@ehsavoie Alright, what if I upgrade wildfly-security to a version that doesn't require an update to the java version? For example 25.0.1.Final? Can that impact the way that JBoss operates? I can see that JBoss EAP 7.4 is based on WildFly 23 but im planning to use 25 fx. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21906

@JamesR.Perkins I am interested in hearing if anyone has experience in upgrading a single dependency in JBoss without upgrading the version of JBoss itself. I can see that WildFly 23 is the version for JBoss 7.4 (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21906), but I don't know what that means in relation to upgrading wildfly-security to be something like 25 for example.

It may or may not work depending on the changes. However, it’s definitely not supported.
